# How to add filter(_:) method to generic structure in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, generics, structure

I want to add a filter(_:) method to Pyramida structure. It should take a single argument, a closure that: takes an Element and returns a Bool, and return a new Pyramida that contains any elements for which the closure returns true, e.g. values higher than 10.

When I used the same code as per (within exercise) already existent func map also for func filter, its implementation prints out just [false, false, true], however not the values above 10.

Also tried to adjust the func filter as per syntax stated within Developer Documentation, however did not manage it further, too many errors.

```
struct Pyramida<Element> {
    var items = [Element]()
 
    mutating func push(_ newItem: Element) {
        items.append(newItem)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        guard !items.isEmpty else {return nil}
        return items.removeLast()
    }

    func map<U>(_ txform: (Element) -> U) -> Pyramida<U> {
        var mappedItems = [U]()
        for item in items {
            mappedItems.append(txform(item))
        }
        return Pyramida<U>(items: mappedItems)
    }

    func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) -> Bool) -> Pyramida<[Int]> {
        var filteredItems = [Int]()
        for item in items {
            if item > 10 {
                filteredItems.append(filteredItems(item))
                return Pyramida(items: filteredItems)
            }
        }
    }
}

var ints = Pyramida<Int>()
ints.push(2)
ints.push(4)
ints.push(11)

var tripled = ints.map{ 3 * $0 }
print(String(describing: tripled.items))

var aboveTen = ints.filter{ 10 < $0} // code func map<U> for filter<U>
print(String(describing: aboveTen.items))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add this method and if the isIncluded is true you have to append the new element in your array.

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Pyramida<Element> {
        var newElements: [Element] = []
        for number in items where try isIncluded(number)  {
            newElements.append(number)
        }
        return Pyramida(items: newElements)
    }
```

and you also can use this.

```
public func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Pyramida <Element>{
        return Pyramida(items: try items.filter(isIncluded))
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply `Pyramida(items: try items.filter(isIncluded))`?

Comment: yes if he want just could call the map function on his array and pass this, filter, just the same as you mention.

Comment: I mean inside your filter method you can simply return this. `func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Pyramida<Element> { .init(items: try items.filter(isIncluded)) }`

Comment: Same for map `func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> Pyramida<T> { .init(items: try items.map(transform)) }`